# Is it legit to create a computed property with a method inside?

Tags: vue.js

I need the logic I use inside a computed property twice. I can't use the computed property itself because of a race condition. So my thought was to put the functionality inside a method and re-write the computed property like this:

```
const filterProjectOptions = () => {
    let options = [];
    if (propData.value.contact_company.projects.billable.length) {
        propData.value.contact_company.projects.billable.forEach((element, index) => {
            options[index] = cloneDeep(element);
            options[index].select_value = element.id;
            options[index].select_label = (element.name ? element.name : "Kein Name");
        })
    }
    return options;
}

const billableProjects = computed(() => {
    let options = filterProjectOptions();
    return options;
});
```

I wonder if the computed property still is as reactive as before or if extracting the logic *might* have side effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the `filterProjectOptions` function is called within the computed property `billableProjects`. The computed property will only recompute its value when one of its reactive dependencies changes.

In this case, since `filterProjectOptions` is called within the computed property, any changes in the reactive dependencies of `filterProjectOptions` will trigger recomputation of `billableProjects`. However, if the reactive dependencies of `filterProjectOptions` do not change, the computed property `billableProjects` will not be recomputed.

If you were to write the entire logic directly inside the computed property, any change in the reactive dependencies within that logic would trigger recomputation of the computed property. However, if the reactive dependencies are used within `filterProjectOptions` but not within the computed property directly, the computed property would not be recomputed unless the result of `filterProjectOptions` changes.

In summary, if the logic inside `filterProjectOptions` relies on reactive dependencies that may change, and you want the computed property to recompute when those dependencies change, calling `filterProjectOptions` within the computed property is the correct approach.

Comment: `if the reactive dependencies of filterProjectOptions do not change, the computed property billableProjects will not be recomputed`


So you basically say, if the reactive dependencies used within the method change (hence the result of it) the computed property also changes its result cause it's observing its content.

Comment: Computed property will be triggered when the result of the method is changed. For example, you're returning `options` from the method and then the method is called inside the computed property, so whenever the value of `options` changes, computed property will be triggered hence recomputing `billableProjects`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Thanks! =)